# Is it possible to write XMLSchema-instance in parent tag as well as child tag?

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I want to create below XML which having **xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"** in "ServiceAddRQ" as well as "Service" tag. SO is it possible to create such XML ?

**Required XML :**

```
<ServiceAddRQ echoToken="DummyEchoToken" version="2013/12"
  xmlns="http://www.test.com/schemas/2005/06/messages"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/schemas/2005/06/messages ServiceAddRQ.xsd">  
        <Service xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ServiceHotel" availToken="1jMqWGjqrx25Bp60gV2Qggb3">
        </Service>
</ServiceAddRQ>
```

**Java Generated XML :** in java generated code I am getting blank xmlns of "Service" tag...

```
<ServiceAddRQ xmlns="http://www.test.com/schemas/2005/06/messages"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" echoToken="6BB6B47EEEF4290515103925"
    version="2013/12"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/schemas/2005/06/messages HotelValuedAvailRQ.xsd">   
    <Service xmlns="" xsi:type="ServiceHotel" availToken="1/YncBXZJXY17Z/ygNiO7gcg">        
    </Service>
</ServiceAddRQ>
```

Java Code For same :

```
    static private Namespace NSSERVICE = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.test.com/schemas/2005/06/messages");
    static private Namespace NSSCHEMA = Namespace.getNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

        String sXMLOut = "";
        Element barceloDS_requests= new Element("ServiceAddRQ",NSSERVICE);  
            barceloDS_requests.setAttribute("echoToken",searchParams.getSessionID().substring(0, 12)+GenTools.getSystemDateWithTime3());
            barceloDS_requests.setAttribute("version","2013/12");
            barceloDS_requests.addNamespaceDeclaration(NSSCHEMA);
            barceloDS_requests.setAttribute("schemaLocation", "http://www.test.com/schemas/2005/06/messages HotelValuedAvailRQ.xsd", NSSCHEMA);

         Namespace xsi = Namespace.getNamespace(GenTools.returnEmptyForNull(sXMLNS_XSI), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
         Element eleService=new Element("Service");
            eleService.setAttribute("type", "ServiceHotel", xsi);
            eleService.setAttribute("availToken",contractInfo[1]);
    barceloDS_requests.addContent(eleService);
    sXMLOut = new GetXMLOutputter().getXMLOutputter(barceloDS_requests,true);
```

Comment: For a question "how can I change my code to produce X instead of Y" you really need to show us the current code that you want to change...  But note that you don't actually need the `xmlns:xsi` declaration in both places because the `Service` element automatically inherits the namespace declarations of its parent.

Comment: Hi @IanRoberts , Thanks for your valuable response. You can check my java code snippet now. Even though child tag inheriting parent tag namespace why I am getting blank 'xmlns' in Service tag?

Comment: Can you confirm which XML object model you're using here as it's definitely not DOM (as in org.w3c.dom).  It looks like JDOM, is that correct?

Comment: yes @IanRoberts you are absolutely correct..I am using JDOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serializer is correct to add the `xmlns=""` because you have created a top-level element with a default namespace declaration but then added a child element that is not in a namespace.  To get the output you want you need to create the `Service` element with the same `http://www.test.com/schemas/2005/06/messages` namespace as the root `ServiceAddRQ`.  Try it more like this:

```
static private Namespace NSSERVICE = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.test.com/schemas/2005/06/messages");
static private Namespace NSSCHEMA = Namespace.getNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

String sXMLOut = "";
Element barceloDS_requests= new Element("ServiceAddRQ",NSSERVICE);  
barceloDS_requests.setAttribute("echoToken",searchParams.getSessionID().substring(0, 12)+GenTools.getSystemDateWithTime3());
barceloDS_requests.setAttribute("version","2013/12");
barceloDS_requests.addNamespaceDeclaration(NSSCHEMA);
barceloDS_requests.setAttribute("schemaLocation", "http://www.test.com/schemas/2005/06/messages HotelValuedAvailRQ.xsd", NSSCHEMA);

// --------------
// Key change -- Create Service element in the right namespace
Element eleService=new Element("Service",NSSERVICE);
// --------------

eleService.setAttribute("type", "ServiceHotel", NSSCHEMA);
eleService.setAttribute("availToken",contractInfo[1]);
barceloDS_requests.addContent(eleService);
```

This will create the correct output of:

```
<ServiceAddRQ echoToken="DummyEchoToken" version="2013/12"
  xmlns="http://www.test.com/schemas/2005/06/messages"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/schemas/2005/06/messages ServiceAddRQ.xsd">  
    <Service xsi:type="ServiceHotel" availToken="1jMqWGjqrx25Bp60gV2Qggb3"/>
</ServiceAddRQ>
```

The `Service` element does not need its own `xmlns:xsi` declaration as this is inherited from the parent, but if you specifically want to add a redundant one anyway then it *may* be possible using `eleService.addNamespaceDeclaration(NSSCHEMA)` but there's no guarantee as the serializer is always free to omit redundant namespace declarations when they don't change the semantics of the result.

Comment: Hi @Ian thanks for revert...will consider your points mentioned in deleted post for future...